# What does 普通に考えたら mean

Tags: meaning

A girl was playing the game of life(人生ゲーム) with her friends and said this (It sounds like this event caused her to go bankrupt):

> あ、交通事故で資産マイナス３００万だって。何コレ**普通に考えたら**速攻で破産なんだけど

What is the difference between saying this and just 何コレ速攻で破産なんだけど.

Answer (score 1):

As a native Japanese speaker my understanding is this.

"普通に考えたら" is just for emphasis in the sentence. Of course you know it means "generally thinking" but that is just a literary meaning. I think in this situation 「あ、交通事故で資産マイナス３００万だって。何コレ普通に考えたら速攻で破産なんだけど」 the person saying this Japanese sentence is very surprised when a traffic accident occurred and the person would like to express his or her feelings to others.

So if you would like to tell others just the situation then you should say "あ、交通事故で資産マイナス３００万だって。速攻で破産なんだけど" on the other hand you would like to tell others the situation made you VERY surprised then you should say "あ、交通事故で資産マイナス３００万だって。何コレ普通に考えたら速攻で破産なんだけど".

However in most cases there is no difference in meaning or nuance between these two sentences, so you don't need to worry. You should think "普通に考えたら" means just an emphatic expression.

Answer (score 0):

普通に考えたら means "generally thinking"